# How can I adjust the brightness of my webcam?

Tags: 10.10, webcam

I have a problem recently my cam (built in) is really really dark when using Skype or cheese I can barely see anything, Only when I spot a light on the cam I can see it but really dark

I have a Sony Vaio F127FD , I am running Ubuntu 10.10 (Desktop edition) fully updated

Note: the webcam was fine I guess the problem has something to do with the latest updates

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at this question and then edit your question adding more detail?   http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If not already installed, install the Video for Linux 2 Universal Control Panel (v4l2ucp), that will allow you to adjust your video settings

Answer (score 36):

Install `guvcview` (still works on 20.04, 22.04):

```
sudo apt install guvcview
```

On **Image Control** tab, there is a **brightness** slider control

Comment: And how do you use this for changing brightness?

Comment: On "Image Control" tab, there is a "brightness" slider control.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, not.  :-)  On my Lenovo T490, the whole panel of the “Image control” tab is empty.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately the control panel, v4l2ucp, has been removed in 20.04 along with all other qt4 applications. The package is still available [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/v4l2ucp), and it installs just fine as long as you have qt4 available from a third-party repo like the one in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234786/qt4-libqt4-in-ubuntu-20-04) answer.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rock-core/qt4` then `sudo apt-get update`. Download [bionic/v4l2ucp](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/v4l2ucp) package then install it `sudo pdkg -i Downloads/v4l2ucp_2.0.2-4build1_amd64.deb`. Fix broken dependencies `sudo apt update --fix-missing` and/or `sudo apt install -f`. Search for **Video4Linux Control Panel** on ubuntu installed apps (`Super key`). Enjoy it!

Comment: Just tried adding that ppa and it's Not Found

Comment: @Shanteva, unfortunately that PPA is for 20.04 only. If you are on 20.10 you will have to find another way of installing qt4. You might be able to use that PPA if you add it manually (click "Technical details about this PPA").

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me (on Debian, probably also works with Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt install xawtv
v4lctl bright 100%
```

Comment: It does work with ubuntu 20.04. (y) Thanks. Nice and simple.

Answer (score 4):

I had a same issue in Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 and struggled a lot with this issue. Changing brightness is certainly the wrong answer.

My camera has its own logic which calculates the brightness according the light conditions (the proportion of the darkest and brightest part of the view).

In this case **Guvcview** is a good solution

```
$ sudo apt install guvcview
```

On **Cap. Image** tab, there are:

- **Exposure, Auto** dropdown: change it to **Manual** Mode
- **Exposure (Absolute)** slider: increase its value carefully till you get a beautiful bright image. It was 320 for me.

I had to do it once and it fixed the issue.