# Ubuntu 20.04 can't install packages

Tags: package-management, software-installation, 20.04, dependencies

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 after using 16.04 for a while.
I'm trying to install the school's VPN client which needs these 3 packages: libqtcore4, libqtgui4 and libgnome-keyring0.

When I try to install with `sudo apt install libqtgui4` I get this error

```
Package libqtgui4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'libqtgui4' has no installation candidate
```

The other two packages threw similar errors.
I manually tried installing packages from copying them over from the 16.04
installation I had with no luck. I tried downloading manually as .deb files
but quickly realized there is no end to the dependency chain.

Is there a way I can install these packages at all?
Or are they not compatible with 20.04?

Comment: What do you know about the technology of "school's VPN"? Is it Cisco, OpenVPN or what?

Comment: See here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234786/qt4-libqt4-in-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: It's called VIA, Virtual Intranet Access I believe

Answer (score 0):

This means the package has been canceled in the new release of Ubuntu. You can search for it on [Ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com) website and download it manually. You'll probably need to download the dependencies manually. Search for them on this website too. If this package worked on 16.04, choose xenial before searching.

Try to find one of these packages and you'll find a list of dependencies. Try to download them manually from xenial repository.

Comment: Well I ended up completely destroying GNOME I think, all I get when I boot is the CLI. I did a clean install now, not trying that again.

Comment: Ok.. You should try these things in a VM first.