# problem with AMD graphic card

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon

my AMD graphic card is the **Radeon HD 6470M** I downloaded the drivers from AMD website but I have some problems with installation and I tried two ways :
First : i doubled click the deb file and it opens the snap store when I click the install button thats whats happen
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goWVe.png)

Second : I tried to install it useing the terminal by the instructions in AMD website using
`sudo dpkg -i` command but thats what I get :

```
 sudo dpkg -i fglrx_15.201-0ubuntu1_amd64_UB_14.01.deb
(Reading database ... 210469 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack fglrx_15.201-0ubuntu1_amd64_UB_14.01.deb ...
dpkg-divert: warning: please specify --no-rename explicitly, the default will change to --rename in 1.20.x
dpkg-divert: warning: please specify --no-rename explicitly, the default will change to --rename in 1.20.x
dpkg-divert: warning: please specify --no-rename explicitly, the default will change to --rename in 1.20.x
dpkg-divert: warning: please specify --no-rename explicitly, the default will change to --rename in 1.20.x
dpkg-divert: warning: please specify --no-rename explicitly, the default will change to --rename in 1.20.x
dpkg-divert: warning: please specify --no-rename explicitly, the default will change to --rename in 1.20.x
dpkg-divert: warning: please specify --no-rename explicitly, the default will change to --rename in 1.20.x
dpkg-divert: warning: please specify --no-rename explicitly, the default will change to --rename in 1.20.x
Unpacking fglrx (2:15.201-0ubuntu1) over (2:15.201-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fglrx:
 fglrx depends on fglrx-core; however:
  Package fglrx-core is not installed.
 fglrx depends on libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta2); however:
  Package libqtcore4 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package fglrx (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fglrx
```

BTW Im new to linux so I'll br thankful if the answers was simple .

Comment: related https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234786/qt4-libqt4-in-ubuntu-20-04